# Mysqli connection in function PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm facing a PHP problem. I've searched the web but couldn't find the answer. This is my code so far:

```
<?php
   $db_host = 'db_host';
   $db_user = 'db_user';
   $db_password = 'db_password';
   $db_name = 'db_name';
   //not showing you the real db login ofcourse

   $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
   if($conn) {
      echo 'We are connected!';
   }
```

Up to here, everyting goes well. The connection is established and 'We are connected!' appears on the screen.

```
function login($username, $password, $conn) {
   $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users");
   echo mysqli_errno($conn) . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

When I run this function however, the mysqli error 'No database selected pops up. So I added the following piece of code the the file before and in the function, so the total code becomes:

```
<?php
   $db_host = 'db_host';
   $db_user = 'db_user';
   $db_password = 'db_password';
   $db_name = 'db_name';
   //not showing you the real db login ofcourse

   $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
   if($conn) {
      echo 'We are connected!';
   }

   if (!mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name)) {
      die("1st time failed");
   }

   function login($username, $password, $conn, $db_name) {
      if (!mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name)) {
         die("2nd time failed");
      }
      $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users");
      echo mysqli_errno($conn) . mysqli_error($conn);
   } 

   $username = 'test';
   $password = 'test';
   login($username, $password, $conn, $db_name);
?>
```

The first time adding the database name works fine, however, in the function it doesn't work. I've also tried using global $conn inside the function but that didn't work either. Changing mysqli_connect() to new mysqli() also doesn't have any effect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this your actual code? $db_name is never assigned.

Comment: There is no point in doing `select_db` multiple times, unless you really are using multiple DIFFERENT databases. Once you select a database, it stays selected for the life of the connection.

Comment: $db_host, $db_user, $db_password and $db_name are defined above this code. As said, the connection is established perfectly, but after that it stops functioning.

Comment: But it's strange that mysqli_select_db doesn't work inside the function right?

Comment: Are you passing in the correct database name as an argument to the login function?  Try seeing what the values are

Comment: I've checked the values, they're all correct. Point is, this actually worked at first when I put the mysqli_connect() and mysqli_close() inside the functions, but I thought that was not the fastest way to do it, so I wanted open the connection only once instead of having to establish the connection in each function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be aware, this code is refactored based on your code, and the login logic is NOT RECOMMENDED. Please try this code and make the changes that you think you need.

Make sure that your Database information is also updated as needed.

MyDB Class

```
Class MyDB {

protected $_DB_HOST = 'localhost';
protected $_DB_USER = 'user';
protected $_DB_PASS = 'password';
protected $_DB_NAME = 'table_name';
protected $_conn;

public function __construct() {
    $this->_conn = mysqli_connect($this->_DB_HOST, $this->_DB_USER, $this->_DB_PASS);
    if($this->_conn) {
        echo 'We are connected!<br>';
    }
}

public function connect() {
    if(!mysqli_select_db($this->_conn, $this->_DB_NAME)) {
        die("1st time failed<br>");
    }

    return $this->_conn;
}
```

}

Login Class

```
Class Login {

protected $_conn;

public function __construct() {
    $db = new MyDB();
    $this->_conn = $db->connect();
}

//This is a HORRIBLE way to check your login. Please change your logic here. I am just kind of re-using what you got
public function login($username, $password) {
    $result = $this->_conn->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username ='$username' AND password='$password'");

    if(!$result) {
        echo mysqli_errno($this->_conn) . mysqli_error($this->_conn);
        return false;
    }

    return $result->fetch_row() > 0;
}
```

}

Usage

```
$login = new Login();
$logged = $login->login('username', 'password');

if ($logged) {
    echo "yeah!! you are IN";
} else {
    echo "boo!! . Wrong username and password";
}
```

Comment: I've looked at the scope but can't figure out how to fix it. Using global $conn inside the function doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, I added 'public' in front of the function and 'return $username . $password;' at the end of the function but now the page doesn't do anything (white screen).

Comment: the public is not the problem the problem is the scope, I am refactoring your code and post it, after I finish it

Comment: Second downvote your "scope" answer. Please read his code again.

Comment: Putting a class around the function returns the same error as in the beginning.

Comment: I read it again.... the OP thinks that the function will get the value from the declaration outside of the function (which is out of scope from the function). Instead of passing the value of `$db_name`. I clearly see that the issue is because he is not passing the value of `$db_name`, but I am trying to explain to him why the value of `$db_name` (in the top) is not picked. sorry if I am not clear enough.

Comment: He is passing the parameters using `login($username, $password, $conn, $db_name);` so your answer doesn't make any sense and only confuse the OP.

Comment: I am glad! Sorry if I confused you with my poor explanation.